# Does pimpl design pattern prevent you from compilation?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

According to this [article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/09/22/make-pimpl-using-unique_ptr/), it's trying to explain the problem which `pimpl` solve but i see that there is no problem in example he showed.

It says that: 
"there is an issue with below design (that could be serious or not, depending on how many clients Fridge has). Since Fridge.h #includes Engine.h, any client of the Fridge class will indirectly #include the Engine class. So when the Engine class is modified, all the clients of Fridge have to recompile, even if they don’t use Engine directly."

```
#include "Engine.h"

class Fridge
{
public:
   void coolDown();
private:
   Engine engine_;
};
```

```
#include "Fridge.h"

void Fridge::coolDown()
{
   /* ... */
}
```

But, i see that if `Engine` is modified, `Fridge` should modify according. And since `Fridge` will modify, the `Client` which uses `Fridge` will also get modified.
In other words, If `Engine` get modified, then `Fridge` should be recompiled and according to that, `Client` also will be recompiled. In this case `Client` modified because `Fridge` is modified NOT because `Engine` is modified.
So, there is no indirection problem in this situation.

Am i right? if yes, So, what's the actual problem does `pimpl` solve? if no, can you give me an indirection example which explain this problem?

Comment: The pimpl design pattern, properly implemented (which this code clearly makes no attempt at doing), solves the problem of any *consumer* of `Fridge.h` from being recompiled on change to `Engine.h`. A proper pimpl would not include `Engine.h` in `Fridge.h`, and therefore changes to `Engine.h` would not affect consumers of `Fridge.h` except *one* : `Fridge.cpp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In other words, If `Engine` get modified, then `Fridge` should be recompiled.

This is correct, but to be more accurate: The functions that depend on `Engine` need to be recompiled.

> and according to that, Client also will be recompiled.

No. Just because translation unit that implements Fridges member functions is recompiled, doesn't mean that Fridges clients would need to be recompiled. Only if Fridge.h is modified, do translation units including that header need to be recompiled.

> But, i see that if `Engine` is modified, `Fridge` should modify according. And since `Fridge` will modify, the `Client` which uses `Fridge` will also get modified.

That is the problem that the shown implementation has. If `Engine` was instead hidden using PIMPL, then a modification to `Engine` wouldn't imply a modification to the `Fridge` class. It only implies modification to the implementation of member functions of `Fridge`, which depend on `Engine` and those implementations are hidden by the PIMPL.

If you take a look at the PIMPL version of `Fridge.h`, you'll notice that it doesn't use `Engine` class directly, and consequently doesn't include `Engine.h`. A change to `Engine.h` therefore doesn't cause changes in `Fridge.h` and therefore doesn't cause changes in translation units that include `Fridge.h`:

> ```
> class Fridge
> {
> public:
>    Fridge();
>    ~Fridge();
>
>    void coolDown();
> private:
>    class FridgeImpl;
>    FridgeImpl* impl_;
> };
> ```

---

> Can you give me example how NOT recompiling Client translation unit after modifying Engine.h will cause issue?

If one translation unit uses a different definition of `Engine` than another translation unit, then the program violates the one definition rule, and the behaviour will be undefined.

With PIMPL, translation units that include `Fridge.h` do not ODR-use `Engine` class at all, so there is no possibility of ODR violation.

Comment: Can you give me example how NOT recompiling `Client` translation unit after modifying `Engine.h` will cause issue?  
I think if we don't recompile `Client` after modifying `Engine.h` will not give us any undesired behavior.